# What does it mean order of consistency $O(h^2)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the equation:
$$-\epsilon u''(x) + \beta u'(x) = 1,\;\; x\in (0,1)$$
$$u(0) = 0, \;\; u(1) = 1,$$
where $\beta >0.$

I have to construct a standard Finite Difference Scheme with order of consistency $O(h^2).$

What does it mean that the finite difference scheme has order of consistency $O(h^2)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you should use the central divided differences
$$
u'(x)=\frac{u(x+h)-u(x-h)}{2h}+O(h^2)
$$
and
$$
u''(x)=\frac{u(x+h)-2u(x)+u(x-h)}{h^2}+O(h^2)
$$
where the error has to be of even order because of the time symmetry of the formulas, and the smallest positive even number is $2$.

---

As you can solve the equation explicitly,
$$
u(x)=\frac xβ+\left(1-\frac1β\right)\frac{\exp\bigl(-\fracβϵ·(1-x)\bigr)-\exp\bigl(-\fracβϵ\bigr)}{1-\exp\bigl(-\fracβϵ\bigr)},
$$
you see that there is a boundary layer at $x=1$ of thickness $ϵ^1$. Thus you will need $h<ϵ/3$ or so to have enough sampling points in the boundary layer so that you get meaningful numerical results.